# Convert an array into Range in excel using formula... OR Second countif not working in Lambda

Tags: arrays, excel, lambda, range, countif

I have the below Lambda Function, wherein I do countif of countif.  The second set of countif is not working

```
=LAMBDA(FirstRng,S1Rng,S2Rng, LET(SecondRng,COUNTIF(FirstRng,S1Rng),ThirdRng,COUNTIF(SecondRng,S3Rng),ThirdRng))(C3:C10,D3:D10,E3:E10)
```

The formula calculates SecondRng correctly but gives #value for the ThirdRng.  Can you help me.

Comment: What do you see if you place the cursor on `SecondRng` in the 2nd `COUNTIF()` function and then evaluate by pressing `F9`? And is it what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The COUNTIF function only works with ranges (not arrays). The results of the SecondRng variable in your LET statement are stored as an array, and therefore cannot be referenced in the subsequent COUNTIF function.

One possible solution would be to use an alternative function in place of the second COUNTIF function. Based on the example provided, the following method will work (assuming the values in range E3:E10 are {0;1;2;3;...}):

```
=LAMBDA(FirstRng,S1Rng,S2Rng, LET(SecondRng,COUNTIF(FirstRng,S1Rng), BYROW(S2Rng,LAMBDA(row,SUM(--(row=SecondRng))))))(C3:C10,D3:D10,E3:E10)
```

Note: I tightened up the LET statement by returning the results of the final calculation directly, rather than declaring the ThirdRng variable.